# Why would native Mac filesystem performance be MUCH worse than various virtualized disks on the same mac?

Tags: macos, filesystem, performance, virtualization

I was attempting to profile a php application when I noticed it was running MUCH slower on my mac vs docker vs virtualbox (all on the same hardware). I started narrowing down possible issues, but now I'm not sure where to go. It seems to be related to the filesystem or core utilities itself, but I'm not sure.

So I started simplifying the problem and the running some tests. I dumped a large number of files from the app (~7.5K files, 74MB total size) as a sample set to perform operations on into a single dir, and then copied the dir to the container, and the vm.

Test 1: `time -p find . -type f -exec md5sum {}  \; > /dev/null`

```
Native | Docker | VirtualBox 
  27s  |   6s   |    5s
```

Test 2: `time -p find . -type f -exec cp {} /dev/null  \; > /dev/null`

```
Native | Docker | VirtualBox
  16s  |   9s   |    7s
```

Test 3: `time -p { dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/delme bs=4k count=100000 && sync; }`

```
Native | Docker | VirtualBox
  0.7s |   0.8s |    0.4s
```

With the first 2 tests, I was trying to test reading and operating on many files using native utils. **OSX was significantly worse**. I was trying to test raw disk speed with the 3rd test.

I know this methodology may be flawed or there may be more accurate way to test, but this is just what I came up with and seemed representative enough for troubleshooting. (More details - I ran each test on each env sequentially, repeated the process 3 times, and took the average. Mac is Catlina 10.15.3 encrypted APFS (no errors reported on the drive). Docker container is `debian:latest`. VB VM is Ubuntu 16.04.

So what's possibly going on here? Am I overlooking something obvious? Is it likely the differences in filesystem performance? I also ran these test on a linux cloud container running on AWS, and had numbers aligned with the Docker/VB VM. Does it have something to do with how virtualized files are typically stored/read? Does the encryption on the native disk matter (since they are all ultimately on this disk)? Could it be some corporate endpoint security process intercepting native read/writes? (I'm unaware of any, but it's a company laptop, and I don't know everything installed, but when I run `sudo htop`, I'm not seeing anything unusual to me.)

Any ideas for further troubleshooting? Using a virtualized layer on top of the native hardware to get a 2-4x improvement just seems wrong.

**Edit 1: Results with disk cache clearing**

So after reading this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845524/echo-3-proc-sys-vm-drop-caches-on-mac-osx

I re-ran the tests with a flushed disk cache and noted the change (∆) between the first and 2nd run.

For Native:
`sync && sudo purge;` run test; run test immediately again;

For Docker and VB:
`echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches;` run test; run test immediately again;

```
Native | Docker | VirtualBox
  ∆5s  |   ∆3s  |    ∆3s
```

There was a clear difference between first and second run, but they all improved with disk caching, and the timings from my original tests indicate a primed a cache for all the original runs that I noted, and the performance difference still remains.

**Edit 2: Sharing a script for others to test/verify**

I wrote a short [script](https://gist.github.com/keithbentrup/8a19298306f80673b416b628cbd12fb3) to create some sample data files, simulate a workload similar to what I described, and print the results. Then I ran it on an older 2015 Macbook that I recently reset and installed Catalina on (so no unknown corporate apps, no *encrypted* APFS, etc.) I tested it natively and using Docker for Mac on that machine. Once again for the limited testing, the linux VM (running docker) on the Mac significantly outperformed OSX. I then tried with my original php app. Same result.

If you try the script and notice significantly different results, please let me know. If anyone has suggestions to improve the script/tests, please do, but otherwise there are certain scenarios/workloads that I just won't be using OSX for from now on and will be using a vm/docker on the Mac instead.

Comment: What kind of drive is installed (HDD or SSD)?

Comment: @klanomath 512GB SSD connected via PCI-Express

Comment: This might need to have all the side questions removed if this gets closed as too broad / un focused , but fascinating write up and data. My gut tells me you are seeing caching and not true disk io or have spotlight issues what the vm avoid. Or you don’t have an oem SSD with a fast Apple controller

Comment: You tests are not accurate - i.e. you're comparing different things. When you do a "sync" inside the virtual machine, it is a completely different thing than a "sync" on the native host. One doesn't really do much, the other ensures that things are written out physically (takes a long time). Similarly, you have much different cache settings and you have probably mounted file systems with differing sync settings, atime settings, etc. I.e. you haven't established a proper basis for comparison yet.

Comment: @jksoegaard The tests are merely meant to be simplification of the original problem. I could drop the 3rd test altogether. I was just trying to understand possible disk issues. Then we could focus on the first 2. What do you recommend that I check (cache, sync, atime, whatever)? Ultimately, I haven't modified anything on the Mac like cache or atime settings (that I'm aware of), and it performs significantly worse for some simple tests that I came up with - just like the original application that led me down this path.

Comment: What I’m trying to say is that you’re comparing two very different things. Even though you think you’re running the same test on both, you’re really not. If you ask a computer to write something into RAM, it does it extremely fast. If you ask the computer to persist something to disk, it is (relatively) extremely slow. The same command (i.e. the characters you’ve typed in) can have different meanings depending on context, so that in one case you ask the system to write into RAM, and the other to disk. Eventually both will end up on disk of course. But just be aware that you can’t compare.

Comment: For example in your first test, you could make the test more comparable by for example : (1) making sure none of the data is in cache (hard when working with virtual machines), (2) ensuring both are using the same md5sum program (install the GNU implementation on macOS for example), (3) ensure that your file systems are mounted with comparable sync/time settings, etc.

Comment: @jksoegaard Fair points, and I fully understood that those could be underlying issues -- that the implementations of `md5sum`, `find`, `cp` wouldn't be the same, nor would the filesystem mount opts, etc. However, I was (am) skeptical that OSX was would make such (poor? questionable?) default choices (re implemenation/disk caching) that these VMs running basic cmds would so significantly outperform the Mac itself, and see that further reflected in higher level languages (like php). If you have some specific optimizations to check/suggest, please do.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm trying to say. This is not about "default choices". I'm saying that you're measuring two _fundamentally_ different things. If you did the reverse test, I'm sure you would also see "surprising" results. I.e. try running macOS inside a virtual machine on Linux, and compare the same tests. You would get something equally skewed.

Comment: So to sum up - you haven't got proper measurements to make a comparison. Therefore you cannot at present conclude that either system is "faster" or "slower" than the other. It simply doesn't work that way. That being said, macOS has never had any kind of reputation for being fast. There's multiple things you can optimize for (for example correctness, ease of use, compatibility, latency, throughput, etc). If you look at it historically, you would often see people praise macOS for low latency, but Linux for high throughput for example.

Comment: I hope you see that there's many factors that make it hard to compare like you do - but just to give a simple example of something that skews your results right now. On Linux you use the GNU md5sum program - this reads the data from disk into cache, and calculates the MD5 sum. When you run it three times in a row, the data is read from disk _once_. On macOS you use the BSD md5 sum program - this reads the data from disk into its own RAM, and calculates the MD5 sum. When you run it three times in a row, the data is read from disk _three_ times.

Comment: The Linux program looks great when benchmarking, but have a habit of hurting overall performance as often you would like to just checksum something, and do not expect to read it again right away. However the macOS version looks bad when benchmarking, but often makes the overall system more performant in a common case. You can tweak either md5 program to work both ways, but it is your choice of md5 programs that makes this difference. Even your very arbitrary choice of averaging the results skews things. Why would an average (i.e. geometric mean) ever be a good idea when benchmarking?

Comment: I saw a similar thing.  When use finder to list the contents of a disk, the native finder was slower then running macos in a virtual machine then using finder to list the contents of a disk.  I was reading from a harddrive. I changed to an ssd to get acceptable performance.  Leads me to believe an issue with the cache in mac os 10.10.5.  Never had this issue in 10.4.11

Comment: I just read your edit 1. The way you're measuring is still wrong, unfortunately - therefore you cannot compare these results in any meaningful way. I have to describe it before, but let me just expand on how the ways you're clearing disk cache is VASTLY different on macOS versus docker/Ubuntu. For macOS you're running commands that force the system to drop disk data cached in RAM, as well as writing out anything in RAM that hasn't been persisted to disk yet. This takes an huge amount of time (relatively) as writing to the physical disk is one of the slowest operations possible.

Comment: [...] In comparison on Docker and VirtualBox you're using drop_caches to clear the disk cache. This means that various data cached in RAM is dropped (i.e. not stored in RAM anymore) - however anything that is not persisted to disk yet is retained in RAM. It does not at all try to save stuff to disk. So this is one difference - however the main difference is that the cache that is cleared is the one inside the virtual host. This means that as far as Docker/VirtualBox knows, the cache has been cleared - but the disk cache that exists in macOS that feeds Docker/VirtualBox is not cleared.

Comment: [...] Essentially this means that Docker/VirtualBox can still read cached data instead of reading from disk. They're just copying memory from the macOS RAM cache to the virtual host RAM cache. This is much, much faster than re-reading it from disk.

Comment: If you want help in improving the performance of your system, and/or discovering the cause of the difference in speeds... please include information about your system setup in your question. I.e. which files systems are you using on macOS/Linux (are you comparing HFS+ to ZFS, or APFS to ext4, or?), what are the mount options used on macOS/Linux, what kind of actual physical disk are we talking about (assuming it is not a network drive or osxfs shared volume or anything like that), etc.

Comment: @jksoegaard You're missing the point. I'm not generally running workloads in unprimed cache states, nor am I clearing the cache on subsequent runs of my app. The cache clearing was mostly to validate caching by the OS was or was not occurring across the platforms. So if whatever default (i.e. not determined by me in my normal course of work/development) caching is occurring on each platform, I'm seeing clear examples of where the linux vm on osx is outperforming osx for the "same" workload, and it's certainly not isolated to the initial machine that I observed it on.

Comment: *outperforming osx for the "same" workload _in primed cache state(s)_ ... adding that last bit to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: @Keith I'm not contesting that... I'm just saying that the benchmarks you have produced are not usable for comparison. If you want to actually solve your issue and get your Mac working with better performance, you need to add the information to the question I requested - i.e. we need specifics on how your machine is setup. Our Macs certainly aren't 5 times slower in native than in virtual machines, and we run tons of complex virtual Linux setups all the time. If your measurements can't be used for comparison, and you won't divulge any information on your setup, it's impossible to help you.

Comment: @jksoegaard I answered your questions re setup in other comments & the original description. Also, I've posted a script for completely reproducible tests. If you run the script natively and on a docker container (or just look thru the code), you can see what I did and what exactly I timed. You can also query the virtualized filesystem to see exactly what it is, but as a modern linux distro you can probably guess what is without trying. You say that I won't divulge any information when that's clearly not true, and I spent a fair amount of time so that others could attempt reproduce my results.

Comment: Okay, please repeat the info then: which file systems, which mount options, what physical hardware...

Comment: The title of your question looks as technically wrong. I suggest you to choose a more appropriate title if you are interested into useful answers and not just sensational or provocative ones.

Answer (score 4):

What you are seeing is the consequence of your hypervisor lying to you about disk **write** flushing, presumably because you have disk writeback caching enabled in the VM configuration. Disable the **write** caching, and you will find the performance is going to be much more similar (probably worse than bare metal).

As a secondary test, you can try on your host by [LD_PRELOAD-ing libeatmydata](https://github.com/stewartsmith/libeatmydata) and you should see that your bare metal performance reaches or surpasses the performance in VMs.